Finding all group homomorphisms from $ {SL}_2\left(\mathbb{C}\right)$ to $\mathbb{C}^*$
I found the below question in a group theory exam question paper :

Find all group homomorphisms from $ {SL}_2\left({\mathbb{C}}\right)$ (group of all $2\times 2$ complex matrices with determinant $1$, under usual matrix multiplication) to $\mathbb{C}^*$ (group of all non zero complex numbers, under complex multiplication).

The only homomorphism that I was able to find is the trivial homomorphism, which maps every element in the domain to $1$. This is essentially the determinant map. Is any other homomorphism possible?
I also tried to solve a similar question by replacing ${SL}_2\left(\mathbb{C}\right)$ with ${GL}_2\left(\mathbb{C}\right)$ :

Find all group homomorphisms from ${GL}_2\left(\mathbb{C}\right)$ (group of all $2\times 2$ complex matrices with non-zero determinant, under usual matrix multiplication) to ${\mathbb{C}}^*$ (group of all non zero complex numbers, under complex multiplication).

Even in this case, the determinant map is a (non-trivial) homomorphism, and we also have the trivial homomorphism. Are there any others?
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

The kernel is a normal subgroup of $SL_2(\Bbb C)$. What are the normal subgroups?

If $\varphi \colon \mathrm{S}\mathrm{L}_2(\mathbb{C}) \to \mathbb{C}^{\ast}$ such a homomorphism, then its kernel is a normal subgroup of $\mathrm{S}\mathrm{L}_2(\mathbb{C})$. What are these?

How to find all normal subgroups of $SL_2(\mathbb{C})$?

Wouldn’t the better idea be figuring out the commutator subgroup of $SL_2(\mathbb{C})$…? I suspect it’s just the entirety of $SL_2(\mathbb{C})$.

As $\mathbb{C}^*$ is abelian, the kernel must contain the commutator subgroup. So, is $SL_2(\mathbb{C})$ perfect (i.e., equal to its own commutator subgroup)?

I was thinking along similar lines, but I am not sure how to prove or disprove that it is simple.

@AvyakthaAchar $\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb{C})$ is not simple, as it has centre ${I, -I}$. (The point of the hints, I believe, are that this is the only proper, non-trivial normal subgroup.) I think this question would be easier to answer if you said what you had learned in the course. For example, did you prove that $\operatorname{PSL}_2(\mathbb{C})$ is simple?

Sorry, I meant perfect, not simple.

No, I don't know what $PSL_2\left(\mathbb{C}\right)$ is.

Here is a direct and elementary proof that $SL_2(\mathbb{C})$ is perfect, i.e., $SL_2(\mathbb{C}) = [SL_2(\mathbb{C}), SL_2(\mathbb{C})]$. Clearly, this implies only such homomorphism is the trivial one.
By considering Jordan canonical form, it suffices to consider the following three cases:

$\begin{pmatrix} a & 0 \\ 0 & a^{-1} \end{pmatrix}$ for some $a \neq 0$. Pick any $b$ s.t. $b^2 = a$. Then,
$$\begin{pmatrix} a & 0 \\ 0 & a^{-1} \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} b^{-1} & 0 \\ 0 & b \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}^{-1}\begin{pmatrix} b^{-1} & 0 \\ 0 & b \end{pmatrix}^{-1} \in [SL_2(\mathbb{C}), SL_2(\mathbb{C})]$$
$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$. We have,
$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} \sqrt{2} & 0 \\ 0 & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} \sqrt{2} & 0 \\ 0 & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \end{pmatrix}^{-1}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}^{-1} \in [SL_2(\mathbb{C}), SL_2(\mathbb{C})]$$
$\begin{pmatrix} -1 & -1 \\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}$. We have, using the results from the first two cases,
$$\begin{pmatrix} -1 & -1 \\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} -1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \in [SL_2(\mathbb{C}), SL_2(\mathbb{C})]$$

This shows $SL_2(\mathbb{C})$ is perfect.
For the question on $GL_2(\mathbb{C})$, we note that any commutator clearly has determinant $1$, so,
$$[GL_2(\mathbb{C}), GL_2(\mathbb{C})] \subset SL_2(\mathbb{C}) = [SL_2(\mathbb{C}), SL_2(\mathbb{C})] \subset [GL_2(\mathbb{C}), GL_2(\mathbb{C})]$$
Thus, $[GL_2(\mathbb{C}), GL_2(\mathbb{C})] = SL_2(\mathbb{C})$. Since $SL_2(\mathbb{C})$ is the kernel of the determinant map, we see that the abelianization $GL_2(\mathbb{C})/[GL_2(\mathbb{C}), GL_2(\mathbb{C})] \simeq \mathbb{C}^\ast$, and the isomorphism is simply induced from the determinant map. Hence, any homomorphism $GL_2(\mathbb{C}) \to \mathbb{C}^\ast$ is given by the composition of the determinant map and a group homomorphism $\mathbb{C}^\ast \to \mathbb{C}^\ast$. (There are more than just the determinant map and the trivial map, since there are plenty more homomorphisms from $\mathbb{C}^\ast$ to itself than just the identity map and the trivial homomorphism, say complex conjugation, or any other field automorphism of $\mathbb{C}$ restricted to $\mathbb{C}^\ast$, for that matter.)

Thank you very much for your answer, but in case 3, why is there a "-1" off the diagonal? Shouldn't it be a "+1"?

Nevermind, we anyways have that the two are conjugate to each other in $SL_2\left(\mathbb{C}\right)$, so it doesn't matter which one we consider : $\left(\begin{matrix} i & 0 \ 0 & -i \end{matrix}\right) \left(\begin{matrix} -1 & 1 \ 0 & -1 \end{matrix}\right) \left(\begin{matrix} i & 0 \ 0 & -i \end{matrix}\right)^{-1} = \left(\begin{matrix} -1 & -1 \ 0 & -1 \end{matrix}\right)$

@AvyakthaAchar Yeah. I just chose $-1$ off the diagonal to make the argument easier.

Yeah, I see that now. Thank you for the neat solution.

(Too long for a comment)
I understood David Gao's proof to show that any homomorphism from $GL_2\left(\mathbb{C}\right)$ to $\mathbb{C}^*$ is the composition of the determinant map and a homomorphism from $\mathbb{C}^* \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^*$ in the  following way :
Let $\phi \rightarrow GL_2\left(\mathbb{C}\right) \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^*$ be a homomorphism. Then $\phi ' :GL_2\left(\mathbb{C}\right)/SL_2\left(\mathbb{C}\right) \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^*$ defined by $\phi ' \left( A \cdot SL_2 \left(\mathbb{C}\right) \right) = \phi \left(A \right) \forall A \in GL_2 \left(\mathbb{C}\right)$ is a homomorphism (it is well defined because $SL_2\left(\mathbb{C}\right)$ is contained in $ker\left(\phi\right)$).
Let $d : GL_2\left(\mathbb{C}\right) / SL_2\left(\mathbb{C}\right) \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^*$ be defined by $d\left(A \cdot SL_2\left(\mathbb{C}\right)\right) = det(A) \forall A \in GL_2\left(\mathbb{C}\right)$.
This $d$ is an isomorphism.
Now, we have $\phi=\left(\phi ' \circ d^{-1}\right)\circ det$, where $\phi ' \circ d^{-1}$ is a homomorphism from $\mathbb{C}^* \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^*$.

This is correct, yes.
